# How to print a form in vb6.0

Tags: printing

i use below code..but it doesn't print whole form.Its only print half form.how to print whole form?

```
    PrintForm1.PrintAction = PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    PrintForm1.Print()
```

[image]

i also use below code but its not working

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            PrintDocument1.Print()
```

Comment: Isn't PrintAction a VB.NET property?

Comment: Maybe you can try the .PrintForm method instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Suzy mentions, PrintForm will send the entire contents of your form to the printer, if that's what you want.  It's a lot like taking a screen shot of your form and sending it to the printer.  If you want something more discriminating, you'll need to use some sort of reporting software.

However, if you got PrintAction to work at all, you're not using VB 6.0, so this might not be your answer.